# How to remove everything before colon in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of `key:value` strings in my dataframe. How can I remove just the keys?

Suppose the dataframe looks like this:

```
   0  1            2            3            4            5            6
0  2  1:-0.860107  2:-0.111111  3:-1         4:-1         5:-1         6:-0.777778
1  2  1:-0.859671  2:-0.111111  3:-0.333333  4:-0.333333  5:-0.111111  6:0.333333
2  2  1:-0.857807  2:-0.555556  3:-1         4:-1         5:-1         6:-0.777778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is also intuitive.

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).split(':')[-1])
```

```
# print(df)

   0          1          2          3          4          5          6
0  2  -0.860107  -0.111111         -1         -1         -1  -0.777778
1  2  -0.859671  -0.111111  -0.333333  -0.333333  -0.111111   0.333333
2  2  -0.857807  -0.555556         -1         -1         -1  -0.777778
```

Answer (score 4):

[`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the keys using the regex `^.+:`, which matches all characters from the beginning to the colon delimiter:

```py
df = df.replace(r'^.+:', '', regex=True)

#    0          1          2          3          4          5          6
# 0  2  -0.860107  -0.111111         -1         -1         -1  -0.777778
# 1  2  -0.859671  -0.111111  -0.333333  -0.333333  -0.111111   0.333333
# 2  2  -0.857807  -0.555556         -1         -1         -1  -0.777778
```

If you want the result to be numeric, chain [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = df.replace(r'^.+:', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```